# Javafx scrollbars position

Tags: javafx, scrollpane

I have a TextArea inside of a ScrollPane.  I have set the TextArea nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT".  When I do this the scrollbars go on the left side of the window instead of the right side, which I assume is default.  How do I force the scrollbars to the right side of the window?

I have tried setting the nodeOrientation of my AnchorPane and ScrollPane to left to right but that did not help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.mycompany.mycalc.MyCalcHistoryController">
   <children>
      <ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane" fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" prefHeight="242.0" prefWidth="400.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <content>
            <TextArea fx:id="txtHistory" editable="false" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" />
         </content>
      </ScrollPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `BorderPane` instead of `AnchorPane` and did not use a `fxml` file. Here is my code and after the code is a screen capture. As you can see, setting the node orientation for the `TextArea` only does not alter the location of the scroll bar on the `ScrollPane`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.NodeOrientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FxTest00 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TextArea txtAr = new TextArea("myxomatosis");
        txtAr.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(txtAr);
        scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(scrollPane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image: FxTst00]

EDIT (after Ray_White's initial comment to my answer)

The scrollbar you are referring to (in your comment) is part of `TextArea` and not related to the `ScrollPane` parent. In the below code, the `TextArea` is added directly to the `BorderPane`, i.e. the below code contains no `ScrollPane`.

The way I found to remove the `TextArea` vertical scrollbar is via the `TextArea` style. I created a CSS file named `scrolbar.css`. Here is its contents:

```
.text-area .scroll-pane {
    -fx-vbar-policy: never;
}
```

And here is the modified code, including your suggestion to add text to the `TextArea` to force scrolling.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.NodeOrientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FxTest00 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TextArea txtAr = new TextArea("myxomatosis");
        txtAr.appendText("\n");
        txtAr.appendText("One");
        txtAr.appendText("\n");
        txtAr.appendText("Two");
        txtAr.appendText("\n");
        txtAr.appendText("Three");
        txtAr.appendText("\n");
        txtAr.appendText("Four");
        txtAr.appendText("\n");
        txtAr.appendText("Five");
        txtAr.appendText("\n");
        txtAr.appendText("Six");
        txtAr.appendText("\n");
        txtAr.appendText("Seven");
        txtAr.appendText("\n");
        txtAr.appendText("Eight");
        txtAr.appendText("\n");
        txtAr.appendText("Nine");
        txtAr.appendText("\n");
        txtAr.appendText("Ten");
        txtAr.appendText("\n");
        txtAr.appendText("Eleven");
        txtAr.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(txtAr);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("scrolbar.css").toString());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And here is the screen capture of the modified GUI. As you can see, no scrollbar.

[image: No scrollbar]

Comment: Put some code in your example to force the scrollbars to be needed, I think you will see they show up on the left side.

Comment: I see what you've done, however, I want scrollbars.  I want the scrollbar on the same side as the text is.  Your example is an option I can use if I'm unable to get what I want.  Thanks